# The snapshot is not represented correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

[image: database screen shoot]

This is the code responsible for uploading text of a post for a blogging app  the text of the post is retrieved correctly and saved in snapshot

```
struct postt {
let username : String!
let textofpost : String!
 }


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var loggedinuser : AnyObject?

var posts = [postt]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

      self.databaseref.child("users").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingle
       Event(of: .value) {(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]

        let username = snapshot["name"] as? String

                      self.databaseref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded,  with: {( snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in


            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

The next variable  textofpost doesn't contain anything and i don't know what is the problem so when i represent the cell only the label appears which has a snapshot from the path name in the node users

```
            let textofpost = snapshot?["text"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(postt(username : username, textofpost : textofpost), at: 0)
             // self.feeds.reloadData()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        )}


}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.posts.count

}




  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt            indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",      for: indexPath)


    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label.text = posts[indexPath.row].username
     let textview = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextView
    textview.text = posts[indexPath.row].textofpost


    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us your Firebase database as well... thanks!

Comment: look at the edit

Comment: Your code matches your database scheme and, as such, should be working fine ;) Are you sure the error isn't elsewhere? Any hints from Xcode console at all?

Comment: when i make a breakpoint at the end of the viewdidload the variable textofpost = nil ((

Comment: Please keep in mind that Firebase *observers* run asynchronously in the background. As such, at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method, neither callback/completion closures have been called yet...

Comment: where should i put my breakpoint ?

Comment: For instance, put in the `self.posts.insert` line instead.